# how to get cookies in vba and store in excel

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function GetCookie(strUrl)
With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", strUrl, False
    .SetRequestHeader "REFERER", strUrl
    .SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
    .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"
    .SetRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5"
    .SetRequestHeader "Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
    .Send
    strCookie = .getAllResponseHeaders
    strCookie = Split(strCookie, vbCrLf)
    GetCookie = Trim(Split(Split(strCookie(5), ";")(0), ":")(1)) & "; " & Trim(Split(Split(strCookie(6), ";")(0), ":")(1))
End With
End Function

Sub get_cookies()
(GetCookie("https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/equity-derivatives-watch"))
End Sub
```

okey the above code work for me
i am new in excel
i wanna know how to store this cookies in excel cell or excel table please help

Comment: `Range("A1").Value = GetCookie(urlHere)`

Comment: You can use any available storage in Excel file itself, for instance - cell or invisible named range.